# Material Components Web - Standalone Initialisation

Tags: wordpress, webpack, material-components, material-components-web

I am trying to include only the components that I need from Material Components Web and I am having trouble getting the components to initialise. The goal is to get all components of the same type to initialise on load so I figured the auto-init would be the way to go.

```js
import mdcAutoInit from '@material/auto-init';
import {MDCTextField} from '@material/textfield';

mdcAutoInit.register('MDCTextField', MDCTextField);
```

```html
<div class="mdc-text-field" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCTextField">
  <input class="mdc-text-field__input" type="text" id="input">
  <label for="input" class="mdc-floating-label">Input Label</label>
  <div class="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
</div>

<!-- at the bottom of the page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.mdc.autoInit();
</script>
```

This renders a console error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'autoInit' of undefined"

I am unsure if I am missing a dependency and I cannot find a concise source for standalone component implementation.

This is a WordPress project. I am also using webpack.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work.

Add 'window.mdcAutoInit = mdcAutoInit;' after importing mdcAutoInit.

```
import mdcAutoInit from '@material/auto-init';
window.mdcAutoInit = mdcAutoInit;
```

Then replace the initialisation script before your closing  tag with:

```
<script>window.mdcAutoInit();</script>
```

The result:

```js
import mdcAutoInit from '@material/auto-init';
window.mdcAutoInit = mdcAutoInit;

import {MDCTextField} from '@material/textfield';
```

```html
<div class="mdc-text-field" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCTextField">
    <input class="mdc-text-field__input" type="text" id="input">
    <label for="input" class="mdc-floating-label">Input Label</label>
    <div class="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
</div>

// add the bottom of the page
<script>
    window.mdcAutoInit();
</script>
```

Make sure you've removed the initialisation script advised by the Material Components Web documentation

```
// remove this
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.mdc.autoInit();
</script>
```

To summarise, this implementation seems to work for importing individual Material components, rather than including the entire material-components-web package.

For reference, the versions I am using:

```
"@material/auto-init": "^0.35.0",
"@material/textfield": "^0.36.0"
```